# dotnet core configuration binding not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration

I am  trying to bind a model from a custom configurationsource, but it wont bind the properties, my class is:

```
public class Secrets
{
    public string DbConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration source returns the correct values, its serialized into a dictionary that has the following key value pair
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB823.png]

Code in my startup is this:

```
 var c = Configuration.GetSection("AWSSecrets").Get<Secrets>();
```

but DBConnectionString is always null, if i do:

```
var config = new Secrets();
        config.DbConnectionString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AWSSecrets:dbConnectionString");
```

then it picks out the property, any idea why my property wont bind automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Get` you need to `Bind` it like this

```
var secrets = new Secrets();
Configuration.GetSection("AWSSecrets").Bind(secrets);
```

In order to access your `DbConnectionString` just do `secrets.DbConnectionString`.

You can also do this in your `startup` and inject in your constructor if you want.

```
services.Configure<Secrets>(Configuration.GetSection("AWSSecrets"));
```

Comment: i have tried this but the property is still null, i don't think the case of the key matters does it?
key = dbConnectionString, property = DbConnectionString

Comment: @DanSharpe casing do matters

Comment: thanks for the help, in the end it was casing, i was under the assumption that it would pick up the different casings like viewmodel binding works

Answer (score 3):

If your appsettings is like below:

```
{
   "AWSSecrets":{
                  "DbConnectionString":""
                }
}
```

First inject your model in startup.

```
 services.Configure<Secrets>(Configuration.GetSection("AWSSecrets"));
```

And access it anywhere using the Ioptions.

```
 private readonly IOptions<Secrets> _secrets;
 public YourClassContructor(IOptions<Secrets> secrets)
 {
     _secrets=secrets;
     string conStr =_secrets.value.DbConnectionString;
 }
```

Make sure your dependency are injected properly. And also you need to have Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions which you can install from package manager.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions nuget package!